Promise somhow escapes to event loop?
I need a self-contained abstraction for debouncing a function call. While deno/async provides such a function, AFAICT there is no way to cancel an already running function (for example, to kill a child process). So, a few days ago, I attempted to implement this requirement myself:
function debounced<T>(
  fn: (signal: AbortSignal) => Promise<T>,
  ms: number,
): () => Promise<T> {
  let controller: AbortController | null = null;
  return async () => {
    controller?.abort();
    controller = new AbortController();
    const signal = controller.signal;
    await delay(ms, { signal });
    return await fn(signal);
  };
}

This test should demonstrate the expected behavior:
Deno.test(async function debouncedAbortsRunningFunctions() {
  // Arrange
  using time = new FakeTime();
  const enter = spy();
  const exit = spy();

  const fn = debounced(async (signal) => {
    enter();

    // simulate a long running function
    await delay(100, { signal });

    exit();
  }, 100); // 100ms delay before calling the function

  // Act
  const p1 = fn();
  time.tick(50);
  const p2 = fn();
  time.tick(150);
  const p3 = fn();

  time.tick(1000);
  const actual = await Promise.allSettled([p1, p2, p3]);

  // Assert
  assertEquals(actual[0].status, "rejected");
  assertEquals(actual[1].status, "rejected");
  assertEquals(actual[2].status, "fulfilled");

  assertSpyCalls(enter, 2); // 2 because the first call was aborted during the delay
  assertSpyCalls(exit, 1); // 1 because the second call was aborted mid-execution
});

However, I'm getting error: Promise resolution is still pending but the event loop has already resolved.
Running equivalent code in NodeJs gives (uncaught error) error: (in promise) AbortError: The signal has been aborted.
I assume that suggests that somhow an unbound/unawaited promise escapes to be a "background task", so the AbortError exception raises to the event loop. I just don't see how and where that could happen.
At this point I have tried numerous implementations of debounced(), using new Promise(...) and whatnot.
I am lost. Any help is appreciated!

What is FakeTime, does it have the ability to run the event loop and promise jobs? p1 and p2 are indeed unawaited while you do time.tick(…).

FakeTime comes from deno/testing. However the problem also occurs when using real timers. I assume FakeTime temporarily replaces setTimeout functions.

How did you use real timers, await delay(50) instead of time.tick(50)?

Yes, await delay(50)

Your test does indeed reject p1 long before it is awaited (through Promise.allSettled), that is where the unhandled rejection is coming from.
I'm not that familiar with deno/testing, but I would suggest you try
// act
const p1 = fn();
const p2 = delay(50).then(fn);
const p3 = delay(200).then(fn);

const promise = Promise.allSettled([p1, p2, p3]);
time.tick(1200);
const actual = await promise;

where no rejection should be able to escape the handling of Promise.allSettled (unless there is a synchronous exception between the promise construction and the allSettled call).

That works with real timers. It does however fail when using FakeTimer. Maybe my mental model is colored by the way futures work in rust.
I was assuming that in typescript a promise won't throw unless awaited.

In JS, the async task for which the promise was created progresses on its own. The promise doesn't need to be polled, it is a notification mechanism to tell the subscribers (plural!) that the result is available. If the promise gets rejected, and there are no subscribers, a global "unhandled rejection" event is fired; even when you meant to add subscribers later.

I don't know what fake timers do, but it might as well be a bug in their implementation.
